# how to fix 'cmd package install-create -r -t -S 1699739' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package'

Tags: android, android-studio

How to fix (**`"cmd package install-create -r -t  -S 1699739' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package"`**) error when i launch the emulator.

```
    'cmd package install-create -r -t  -S 1699739' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package'
```

> 20:20  Session 'app': Install failed.
>               Installation failed
>               Rerun

Comment: I have a similar problem: `Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t -S 2346616' returns error 'Unknown failure: Can't find service: package''` with Android Studio 3.5. This is with the emulator, which does not complete the boot sequence. Cold boot did not help.  The first error in the logcat was`1970-01-01 08:00:04.067 867-893/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory` the lots of similar errors, then `1970-01-01 08:00:09.971 902-902/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib64/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/egl/...`

Comment: Also: this is only happening for me with an arm64 image. An x86_64 image boots fine.

Comment: I had a student who created the project on OneDrive. Once he created the project on c: drive, the problem went away.

Answer (score 48):

It's not your fault. The problem is with the functionality of emulator .

SO,

Close the Emulator.

Go to AVD manager and edit virtual device Quick Boot to Cold Boot.

Comment: May 2023 still happens :(

Answer (score 17):

Try the following steps:

1. Close the emulator
2. Cold boot app
3. Clean Build
4. Open emulator
5. Run app

Answer (score 14):

1- Close your emulator

2- Go to AVD Manager

[image]

3- Click the down arrow next to your emulator -> cold boot now

[image: cold boot now]

Answer (score 10):

I had same problem. This is what I did.

1. Force quit the emulator.
2. Go to Android Studio, Click on AVD Manager.
3. In the action column (last column), click the arrow facing down.
4. Click Cold Boot Now.
5. Run code from Android Studio again. Things should run normally.

Usually, this happened because the emulator freeze due to the laptop goes to sleep for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to run the app again. I was also having the similar problem but when i run the app again, the issues got fixed. If it doesn't solve the problem then create a new adv and start launching your app on it.

Answer (score 0):

Do check once if there are multiple instances of emulator running. I got this error when I had 2 instances of emulator running.

Answer (score -1):

- Go To AVD Manager on Android studio
- Select the Edit option
- Select Boot Option as "Cold Boot"
- Launch the Emulator
  This should fix your problem

Comment: Already explained in several answers.