# How to fix Installation failed due to: "Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package"

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, android-virtual-device

When I am running the AVD from the compiler, it display this error message to me and prompted me to retry.

Activity Logs :

```
07/18 23:37:45: Launching 'app' on He.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] '/Users/IdeaProjects/testing2/app/build/intermediates/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: ''package install-create -r -t --user current --full --dont-kill --skip-verification -S 4475820' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package''
Retry
Failed to launch an application on all devices
```

Note : I am currently using an intel mac

The problem occurs when I added a new Pixel 5 virtual devices. I have change from quick boot to cool boot but the issues remain same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fix 'cmd package install-create -r -t -S 1699739' returns error 'Unknown failure: cmd: Can't find service: package'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57256664/how-to-fix-cmd-package-install-create-r-t-s-1699739-returns-error-unknown)

Comment: @JustSightseeing Hi. I did tried out this methods before. However, the problems remain the same. I have solve this problems but when I am running the avd, it show the lauch succeed but the avd is not opening. Do you know this problems ?

Comment: I would probably try -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/70981809/15749574 OR open the emulator from android studio and then try running the app (and making sure the correct device is selected)